# How to start use webservice

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

i want to read and write data to a website (server on web) and don't have any information about webservices and other things that related to it
Does anybody have any idea about how to start it (mean offer complete books,papers,tutorials,websites,… or what should i learn at first mean is it necessary to learn xml,soap,... and other things)

Thank you

Comment: Does the web service exist or are you trying to create your own?

Comment: Good question, Jeff. My answer is based on that I you want to create a service.

Comment: Yes my friend want to create it and i use it on iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Google App Engine with great success. You would format your data to output as JSON and use an iPhone library to read it. I've used [this](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) one (though [Touch JSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) seems to be more popular).

Answer (score 0):

Read about REST, ROA and AtomPub. Thats got me started. I'm about to implement some webservices in WCF (WCF now acts like a RESTFul webservice, but you can also use plain old SOAP). Before I got to WCF, I experimented with RoR. RoR uses REST "out-of-the-box".